# Java UrlDecode not wotking when we send encoded value from URl

Tags: java, urldecode

When we initialize the string in class with same value it decodes it properly.When get same string from url it is not able to decode it.We are using "UTF-8".Below is the code for doing it.Any Suggestions.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  SendSMS sendSMS = new SendSMS();
  sendSMS.sendSMS("", "");

  try{
     String sms="#E0#A4#B8#E0#A5#81#E0#A4#B6#E0#A4#BF#E0#A4#B2#20";
 sms=sms.replaceAll("#","%");        
  System.out.println( URLDecoder.decode(sms,"utf8"));

  }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

  }
}
```

It works properly.

```
 System.out.println("actural sms ="+sms);
      sms=sms.replaceAll("#","%");
   System.out.println("compared"+sms.equals("%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A6%20"));
     log.info("sms before formating= ");
     log.info(sms.trim());
 System.out.println( URLDecoder.decode(sms,"utf8"));





    in.close();*/

 }catch(Exception e){
     log.error("error occured while sending message:-"+e.getMessage());
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Here it is not working properly.The output of .equals() is true..Yet the decoder gives ?????..

Answer (score 1):

> ***The output of .equals() is true***

[No, it's not.](http://ideone.com/CPqRW)

> ***Yet the decoder gives ?????***

For me it gives सुशिल